# finding a tableView cells superView

Tags: ios, slider, uislider, rangeslider

I am trying to create a range slider that has labels representing the sliders handle value. I have the slider enabled but when I try to add the labels to the sliders subview, my app crashes with the error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The slider is inside of a tableViewCell and I am initializing this cell inside of the tableView VC with the code below,

```
if indexPath.section == 2 {
        let costRangeCell = AgeRangeCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

        let contentView = costRangeCell.rangeSlider.superview!
```

// my declaration of contentView is where my app is crashing.

```
        costRangeCell.rangeSlider.minimumValue = 0
        costRangeCell.rangeSlider.maximumValue = 100
        costRangeCell.rangeSlider.lowValue = 0
        costRangeCell.rangeSlider.highValue = 100
        costRangeCell.rangeSlider.minimumDistance = 20

        let lowLabel = UILabel()
        contentView.addSubview(lowLabel)
        lowLabel.textAlignment = .center
        lowLabel.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 60, height: 20)

        let highLabel = UILabel()
        contentView.addSubview(highLabel)
        highLabel.textAlignment = .center
        highLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 20)

        costRangeCell.rangeSlider.valuesChangedHandler = { [weak self] in
          
        let lowCenterInSlider = CGPoint(x:costRangeCell.rangeSlider.lowCenter.x, y: costRangeCell.rangeSlider.lowCenter.y - 30)
        let highCenterInSlider = CGPoint(x:costRangeCell.rangeSlider.highCenter.x, y: costRangeCell.rangeSlider.highCenter.y - 30)
        let lowCenterInView = costRangeCell.rangeSlider.convert(lowCenterInSlider, to: contentView)
        let highCenterInView = costRangeCell.rangeSlider.convert(highCenterInSlider, to: contentView)

        lowLabel.center = lowCenterInView
        highLabel.center = highCenterInView
        lowLabel.text = String(format: "%.1f", costRangeCell.rangeSlider.lowValue)
        highLabel.text = String(format: "%.1f", costRangeCell.rangeSlider.highValue)
        }
        
        costRangeCell.rangeSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleMinAgeChange), for: .valueChanged)
        let minAge = user?.minSeekingCost ?? SettingsViewController.defaultMinSeekingCost
        costRangeCell.rangeLabel.text = " $\(minAge)"
        return costRangeCell
    }
```

Is there a different way for me to gain access to the cells range slider superView?

ageRange class,

```
class AgeRangeCell: UITableViewCell {

let rangeSlider: AORangeSlider = {
    let slider = AORangeSlider()
    slider.minimumValue = 20
    slider.maximumValue = 200
    return slider
}()


let rangeLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = costRangeLabel()
    label.text = "$ "
    return label
}()




class costRangeLabel: UILabel {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return .init(width: 80, height: 50)
    }
}

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let overallStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [
        UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [rangeLabel, rangeLabel]),
        ])
    overallStackView.axis = .horizontal
    overallStackView.spacing = 16
    addSubview(overallStackView)
    overallStackView.anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 16, left: 16, bottom: 16, right: 16))
    
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

  }
```

AORangeSlider is a custom Slider.

Comment: Wrong approach. If you are going to have varying numbers of labels (or other UI elements) in your cells, you should write your cell class to do that work. You should *not* do it in `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: @DonMag so I should be manipulating this cell inside of the tableViewCell itself?

Comment: Yes, it should be done inside the cell class. Your question shows: `if indexPath.section == 2` ... does this mean you will have several rows in that section with sliders and labels in them? Or do you have just one row in that section? Are you designing your cell(s) as Prototypes in Storyboard? or creating them via code only?

Comment: @DonMag I am using code only. The indexPath.section is the tableView section. Only this section has a rangeSlider the rest are textBoxs. In indexPath.section == 2 the only object inside of it is the rangeSlider

Comment: ok - so that cell will have a slider, a rangeLabel, a lowLabel and a highLabel? Or will it sometimes have only one, two or none of them? Or maybe something else?

Comment: correct. I am going to delete the rangeLabel because it is not necessary if I can see the low label and high label. It will always have rangeSlider, lowLabel and highLabel.. @DonMag

Comment: and are you trying to move the low/high labels as the slider changes? or only change the text in those labels?

Comment: @DonMag The labels will be connected to the slider Handles. As the slider handles move, the attached labels move with them. as well as updating their text to represent the value of the label.

Comment: ok - show your `AgeRangeCell` class, and whatever class you're using as your `rangeSlider` (I'm assuming it's a custom class, as `UISlider` does not have "handles").

Comment: @DonMag I have updated question to show ageRangeCell

Comment: ok - hang on a few minutes... I'll give you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a look at `AORangeSlider`...

You want to implement your label tracking inside your custom cell... *not* in your controller class.

Here's a simple implementation, based on the code you supplied in your question:

```
class AgeRangeCell: UITableViewCell {
    let rangeSlider: AORangeSlider = {
        let slider = AORangeSlider()
        slider.minimumValue = 0
        slider.maximumValue = 100
        return slider
    }()

    let lowLabel = UILabel()
    let highLabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        lowLabel.textAlignment = .center
        lowLabel.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 60, height: 20)
        
        highLabel.textAlignment = .center
        highLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 20)
        
        [rangeSlider, lowLabel, highLabel].forEach {
            contentView.addSubview($0)
        }
        
        rangeSlider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            rangeSlider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            rangeSlider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            rangeSlider.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            rangeSlider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
        ])
        
        // avoid auto-layout complaints
        let c = rangeSlider.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        c.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
        c.isActive = true


        rangeSlider.valuesChangedHandler = { [weak self] in
            guard let `self` = self else {
                return
            }
            let lowCenterInSlider = CGPoint(x:self.rangeSlider.lowCenter.x, y: self.rangeSlider.lowCenter.y - 30)
            let highCenterInSlider = CGPoint(x:self.rangeSlider.highCenter.x, y: self.rangeSlider.highCenter.y - 30)
            let lowCenterInView = self.rangeSlider.convert(lowCenterInSlider, to: self.contentView)
            let highCenterInView = self.rangeSlider.convert(highCenterInSlider, to: self.contentView)
            
            self.lowLabel.center = lowCenterInView
            self.highLabel.center = highCenterInView
            self.lowLabel.text = String(format: "%.1f", self.rangeSlider.lowValue)
            self.highLabel.text = String(format: "%.1f", self.rangeSlider.highValue)
        }
        
    }
}

class RangeTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // register your "slider" cell
        tableView.register(AgeRangeCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ageRangeCell")

        // register any other cell classes you'll be using
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "plainCell")

    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 2 {
            return 1
        }
        return 2
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        if indexPath.section == 2 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ageRangeCell", for: indexPath) as! AgeRangeCell

            cell.rangeSlider.minimumValue = 0
            cell.rangeSlider.maximumValue = 100
            cell.rangeSlider.lowValue = 0
            cell.rangeSlider.highValue = 100
            cell.rangeSlider.minimumDistance = 20

            return cell
        }
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "plainCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath)"
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Section Header: \(section)"
    }
}
```

That code will produce this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: Hey I just had a quick side question, I would like to save these values into firebase database, Is there a way for me to access the values inside the cell after the user has lifted his finger and save it on the original tableView?